# Is there a way to blacklist arbitrary text, like for spam reduction?

Tags: support, spam-detection

I've seen a persistent spammer hitting at least [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) and [Super User](http://superuser.com) with his advertising for `piratesystem[dot]net`. (Here's a deleted [example](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34924/everyone-who-looking-to-download-apk-file-for-android-come-here).)

It's probably not a bot, because he's changing up the text and getting past the other anti-bot measures. I think there might already be a link ban, because the last few messages haven't tried to link and have just had the URL in plain text.

Is there a way to prevent particular strings from being allowed in posts? There'd probably need to be some magical regex involved, too, to account for the munging that he seems to be doing lately. Or something that would cause posts to be auto flagged?

Is it even practical to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inputs can be (and have been) blacklisted. This is on a site by site basis.

Make a case for the blacklist on each site's meta.

I can't see there being any disagreement, so all that it will require is for the moderators to ask someone from SE to do the necessary as it's not something that we can do from this end.

Answer (score 3):

There is a blacklist; it's most often used for *tags* (like intrinsic tags, so Programming can't exist on Stack Overflow) or to temporarily block posts with a certain (spam) URL. It's developer-only, but moderators can (and do) ask a dev/the community team to block a URL/text. As a normal user I'd just raise an "Other" flag and note that we're getting a lot of spam involving (keyword/URL). Blacklisting is pretty extreme but it does happen when suspending/deleting posts is no longer enough.